# PineScript v5, working with arrays and for loops

Tags: arrays, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to write an indicator whose purpose is to identify support levels based on fractals.
This code shows conditions only for lower fractals (to make it easier to navigate the code).

The main problem is the for loop - it constantly produces an error:
**Error on bar 6: In 'array.get() function. Index -1 is out of bounds, array size is 1.**

I tried to iterate through the values ​​in a for loop, but after numerous attempts, it seems to me that I do not understand the logic of the loop working with arrays of data.
Details are written in the code itself in the form of comments.

```
//@version=5

indicator('Williams Fractals', shorttitle='WICK.ED Fractals', overlay=true, max_bars_back = 100)

n = 2

var int[] barIndexes = array.new_int()


upFractal = low[n - 1] > low[n] and low[n + 1] > low[n]

if upFractal
    array.push(barIndexes, bar_index)



f_indexes(barIndexes) =>
    if array.size(barIndexes) > 0
        for i = array.size(barIndexes) - 1 to 0 by 1 //The purpose of this cycle: Iterate through the indices of bars that meet the upFractal condition.
            PreviousBarIndex = array.get(barIndexes, i - 1) //PreviousBarIndex is the index of every first bar (if you read the chart from left to right).
            CurrentBarIndex = array.get(barIndexes, i) //CurrentBarIndex is the index of every second bar (if you read the chart from left to right).
            PreviousBarLow = low[PreviousBarIndex]
            CurrentBarClose = close[CurrentBarIndex]
            CurrentBarOpen = open[CurrentBarIndex]
            if CurrentBarOpen > CurrentBarClose //If open is greater than close, then it is a red candle - the logic is written for it.
                isPreviousBarOpenLesser = PreviousBarLow > CurrentBarClose //If Previous Low is greater than Current Close, then the price has “broken” the previous fractal
                if isPreviousBarOpenLesser
                    label.new(bar_index[n], low, text="yes", yloc=yloc.belowbar) //If the above condition is met, mark where exactly
                if array.size(barIndexes) > -100 //an attempt to limit the maximum number of array elements to avoid errors
                    array.shift(barIndexes)
f_indexes(barIndexes)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        for i = array.size(barIndexes) - 1 to 0 by 1 //The purpose of this cycle: Iterate through the indices of bars that meet the upFractal condition.
            PreviousBarIndex = array.get(barIndexes, i - 1) //PreviousBarIndex is the index of every first bar (if you read the chart from left to right).
```

when i = 0 `PreviousBarIndex = array.get(barIndexes, i - 1)` points to -1 element which is not exists